# Ext Quivers and their applications to Representation Theory

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, quivers

I am looking for references that provide an overview of the following two topics (it can be multiple references if necessary):

1. How to compute the Ext-quiver of a (locally finite or finite) $\mathbb{C}$-linear abelian category.
2. How to apply the Ext-quiver to representation theory problems.

The second question is quite vague but I am looking for applications in a similar vein to those in [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0202184) paper by Jerome Germoni on Indecomposable Representations of Special Linear Superalgebras. The references don't have to only be related to Superalgebras though.

I would prefer references in the form of texts which develop the theory of Ext-quivers in relation to representation theory more systematically and in more generality. I would, however, also be very happy with texts which just go over useful examples.

Comment: Did you look at the book of Assem et al?

Comment: I have not. Could you give me the name of the book please?

Comment: http://books.google.com/books/about/Elements_of_the_Representation_Theory_of.html?id=ayNHpi3tYhQC

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I will look through it to see if it has what I want.